# Angular Chart.js - Remove Moment.js as Dependency / Reduce Bundle Size

Tags: angular, dependencies, chart.js, momentjs, angular7

I am using `Chart.js` with `Angualar 7`.

But `Chart.js` adds about 450KB to my bundle size. Through other resources I found out, that `Moment.js` is the main factor for the big size.

```
"chart.js": {
      "version": "2.7.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chart.js/-/chart.js-2.7.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-3+7k/DbR92m6BsMUYP6M0dMsMVZpMnwkUyNSAbqolHKsbIzH2Q4LWVEHHYq7v0fmEV8whXE0DrjANulw9j2K5g==",
      "requires": {
        "chartjs-color": "^2.1.0",
        "moment": "^2.10.2"
      }
    },
```

I want to know how to remove `moment.js` from the dependencies, so that bundle size will be reduced.

Mybe there is a way to only import what's I am really using from `Chart.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import standalone version - not bundled one with the following line:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/dist/Chart.js'
```

Or setting alias in web.config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'chart.js': 'chart.js/dist/Chart.js'
    }
}
```

Or
Install Angular ChartJS which does not have moment.js bundled:

https://github.com/emn178/angular2-chartjs