# Replacing moment.js with date-fns having chart.js installed

Tags: node.js, angular, momentjs, node-modules, date-fns

I have an angular app using **moment.js** and **chart.js** modules.

After replacing **moment.js** with **date-fns** I noticed that the size of the **vendor.js** file increased while it should've been decreased. After visualizing the content of it and searching for any dependencies on **moment.js** I saw a few things:

1. **moment.js** wasn't deleted from `node_modules` but only from package.json after using `npm prun` and `npm uninstall moment --save` and more..
2. The **vendor.js** file contains both the **date-fns** and **moment.js** modules.
3. **package-lock.json** list **moment.js** as a dependency of my project and it's a dependency of **chart.js** too.

First of all, I'd like to confirm that the reason the **moment.js** appears in all of the above is that it's **chart.js's** dependency.

Secondly, how can I truly remove **moment.js** and get the **vendor.js** to be lighter?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, ***moment.js*** is a ***chart.js***'s dependency. [Here are a few options to avoid importing ***moment***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111241/8932655)

Your size bundle increased because now you have ***moment*** and ***date-fns***

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried that but the **moment.js** is still exists in the dependencies and compiled to the **vendor.js**.. Do you know if there's another way to use chart.js without having the **moment.js** as a dependency?

Comment: Yes, since **angular2–chart.js** has **chart.js* on it’s dependencies and **chart.js** has **moment.js** it doesn’t work..